# Make hidden element appear for X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I simply try to show an hidden element for X seconds after I click on a button.
I am able to make it appear, but not to let it dissapear again after X seconds have passed. I tried it with `delay(X)` but nothing happens.

```js
$("#mybutton").on(
  "click",
  function() {
    $("#test").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#test").delay(1000).css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
);
```

```css
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#mybutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybutton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  float: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Minimal-jQuery-Loading-Overlay-Spinner-Plugin-Easy-Overlay.jpg">

<div id="mybutton">
  Button
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/75sttmxj/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `setTimeout()` at this context,

```
setTimeout(() => { $("#test").css("visibility", "hidden"); }, 1000 * 1000);
```

Since `.delay()` can delay the animation queue only.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/75sttmxj/3/)

And if you don't want to use an `arrow function` to do that, then you could simply use normal `anonymous function` like below,

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#test").css("visibility", "hidden"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: the delay is in milliseconds (the 1000) at the end, which is 1 second.

Comment: @Aziz No user's are going to stay in a page for 1000 seconds continuously.  But anyway changed it as per OP's requirement. :)

Comment: raja, what is the difference between `setTimeout(()=>{...});` and `setTimeout(function() {...});`?

Comment: Keep in mind that arrow functions `() => { }` are not implemented everywhere yet.

Comment: Would be nice if you can make your code executable like mine.

Comment: @Aziz Its ES6 arrow function

Comment: @Aziz, they're [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @EdwardBlack Do you really want that element to be hidden after 1000 secs?

Comment: @EdwardBlack See the demo given in my answer

Comment: i mean executable on stackoverflow, this would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as above but then supported by all browsers

```js
$("#mybutton").on
(
  "click",
  function()
  {
   $("#test").css("visibility","visible");
        setTimeout(function () 
        {
            $("#test").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, 1 * 1000);
  }
);
```

```css
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#mybutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mybutton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Minimal-jQuery-Loading-Overlay-Spinner-Plugin-Easy-Overlay.jpg">

<div id="mybutton">
    button
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> .delay()
>
> The .delay() method allows us
>   to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It
>   can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue.
>   Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

so you could use, for example **fade**:-

```js
$("#mybutton").on("click", function() {
  $("#test").fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
#mybutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybutton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">

<div id="mybutton">
  button
</div>
```

or create a custom queue:-

```js
$("#mybutton").on("click", function() {
  $("#test").queue(function() {
      $(this).css("visibility", "visible").dequeue();
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function() {
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden").dequeue();
    });
});
```

```css
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#mybutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybutton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="test" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">

<div id="mybutton">
  button
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try animating the opacity:

```js
$("#mybutton").on(
  "click",
  function() {
    $("#test").animate({
      "opacity": 1
    }).delay(1000).animate({
      opacity: 0
    });
  }
);
```

```css
#test {
  opacity: 0;
}
#mybutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybutton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  float: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Minimal-jQuery-Loading-Overlay-Spinner-Plugin-Easy-Overlay.jpg">

<div id="mybutton">
  Button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mybutton").on( "click",  function() {
        console.log('---------');
        $("#test").css("visibility", "visible");
        setTimeout(function () {
   $("#test").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, 1000);
       
      });
      });
```

```css
 #test {
      visibility:hidden;
    }
    #mybutton:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #mybutton {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: gray;
      float: top;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img id="test" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Minimal-jQuery-Loading-Overlay-Spinner-Plugin-Easy-Overlay.jpg" />

    <div id="mybutton">
      Button
    </div>
```

try this code :

for more [reference](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/)